# Where do I set the environment parameters while calling custom java classes from nashorn script

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

```
//Custom Java class
package com.xxx.yyyyyy.summary.Entry;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Summarize {
}
```

This is the class file and this cannot be referenced from Nashorn Script

And JavaScript jjs response

```
var MyJavaClass = Java.type('com.xxx.yyyyyy.summary.Entry.Summarize');
```

This does NOT work

```
var MyJavaClass = Java.type('java.lang.Boolean');
```

This works fine

This is related to some class path - so where to add it?

Comment: JavaScript has nothing to do with Java. Please learn that.

Comment: @epascarello In this case it does, as nashorn is a Javascript engine inside Java.

Comment: @zyexal That is not a duplicate for this question, this is about accessing Java classes from the Javascript engine (Nashorn) inside Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jjs supports -classpath option and you've to specify classpath for your application classes that are accessed from javascript.

See also : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jjs.html

Comment: Thank you- It is now working for me. Now I'm struggling where to set this in LucidWorks Fusion, next month we have advisory hours with them- hopefully it gets resolved.